# Run script as root whenever any user logs in

Tags: macos, script, launchd, login-items, root

What's the best way to run a script with root privileges whenever any user logs in? It should run in the background without prompting the user for a password.

Comment: Logs in through the Finder GUI or opens a terminal prompt?

Comment: Through the GUI

Answer (score 2):

Use a LoginHook.

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /path/to/script
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CustomLogin.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found a way to do exactly this, but since the script I need to run is just a chmod command, it's sufficient to run it via a launchdaemon every 10 seconds instead.